# Android: java.lang.SecurityException

Tags: java, android, service, android-gps

Am trying to fetch latitude and longitude in the service class by using network provider.Giving all the permission in the manifest

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

But when I try to run the application am getting an security exception

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service test.alaramservicedemo.GPSTracker: java.lang.SecurityException: "network" location provider requires ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission.
```

**GPSTracker.java**

```
public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

private static final String TAG = "HelloService";

private boolean isRunning  = false;
protected LocationManager locationManager;
String latitude = "";
String longitude="";
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Log.i(TAG, "Service onCreate");
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
    isRunning = true;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Service onStartCommand");

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }

                if(isRunning){
                    Log.i(TAG, "Service running latitude "+latitude + " longitude " +longitude);
                }
            }

            stopSelf();
        }
    }).start();

    return Service.START_STICKY;
}


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Service onBind");
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {

    isRunning = false;

    Log.i(TAG, "Service onDestroy");
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    latitude = ""+location.getLatitude();
    longitude = ""+location.getLongitude();

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

}
```

}

The GPSTracker is calling form the onReceive() method from BroadcastReciver

```
 Intent i = new Intent(context, GPSTracker.class);
    context.startService(i);
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <!-- Will not be called unless the application explicitly enables it -->
    <receiver android:name=".DeviceBootReceiver"
        android:enabled="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name=".GPSTracker"/>
</application>
```

I don't know why even am giving the permission in Manfiest why am getting security exception.

Can any one please help to find out the issue

Comment: Are you testing this in marshmallow?

Comment: no, am running in Kitkat @Vivek Mishra

Comment: then are you using android studio 2 and above using instant run feature?

Comment: Could you share AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: question updated with manifest @Miguel Benitez

Comment: Permissions go outside of the `<application>` tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write your permission outside application tag. Like this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <activity
                android:name=".xxxxx"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```
 locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
```

Instead of :

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
```

If you are calling the service a GPSTracker.

Comment: am running in Kitkat @Enpi

Answer (score 0):

Try following permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
```

also apply following

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

it may be solve  your problem.

Comment: I try, but still the same problem @Dhavalkumar Solanki